# Network problems after Jailbreakme on iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, network

I recently jailbroke my iPhone 3gs with jailbreakme.

At the beginning everything was working well. But since yesterday I am having problems with the network. It would disconnect from wifi and there is no way that I can reconnect until I reboot my phone. It happened twice so far, but I am not able to reproduce the problem as it doesn't happen all the time.

Anyone here has any hint on what I should check?

---

**Edit:** I found out that this problem occurs if it changes wifi network.

**Edit:** Resetting the network settings was the right solution for me. 
Does anyone know if this is a common problem? ( I was not able to find anything with google )

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me too, and now my wifi doesn't work anymore so you should expect that. (not much an answer just a comment)

3 possible fixes you can try: **(they did not work for me)**

1) Reset network settings: Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings.
3) When connected to your network click more info (the little > icon) and check if DHCP is enabled.
2) The last thing Restore your device from Itunes or reset the device from Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I started to notice that it happened to 
me when I change wifi network. 
Is it the case also for you?

Comment: @Vlad answers are expected to help resolve the question. If you get 50 reputation you'll be able to comment directly. If you have any other Stack Exchange accounts with 200+ reputation you'll get 100 on this site for associating them. I'm going to delete this answer. If you have a solution to the problem feel free to edit your answer and flag it for moderator attention so it can be undeleted.

Comment: something strange happened on this website: I was only able to 
see only half the comment and this is the reason why I replied that way. 

Solution 1) worked so far. Hopefully the problem  will not appear again.

Comment: yes this is a really common problem too bad it wont work for me too :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting your network settings?

Here's how to do it:

Settings >> General >> Reset >> Reset Network Settings.

That usually solves network problems. If it doesn't work for you, please post back here and I'll try to help some more.

Comment: yes, thanks... this solution worked for me
Do you know what exactly happen during network reset?

Comment: Cool. Glad it worked. It resets all network connections (WiFi, 3G/ EDGE, Bluetooth). Clears stored networks, passwords, etc, so when the phone reboots, all communications have to be renegotiated. I tried to find a decent article on support.apple.com, but this was all I could find: 

"When you reset network settings, your list of previously used networks and VPN settings not installed by a configuration profile are removed. Wi-Fi is turned off and then back on, disconnecting you from any network you’re on. The Wi-Fi and “Ask to Join Networks” settings are left turned on." http://bit.ly/ckuMb8

Comment: Thanks again. I wonder why this tricks solves the problem that I had, since I tried to reboot but it was not enough. 
Probably it is related with the permission of some special files.